# unable to append to table

Tags: r, database, oracle, data-analysis

I am trying to run the below R code :

```
idisc_ODBC <- odbcConnect("TEST",'sys', "oracle123",rows_at_time = 1)
ColumnsOfTable<- sqlColumns(idisc_ODBC, "GAData5")

varTypes <- as.character(ColumnsOfTable$TYPE_NAME) 
names(varTypes) <- as.character(ColumnsOfTable$COLUMN_NAME) 
colnames(gaData)<- as.character(ColumnsOfTable$COLUMN_NAME)

sqlSave(
  channel = idisc_ODBC,
  dat = gaData,
  tablename = "GAData5",
  append=TRUE,
  rownames = FALSE,
  varTypes = varTypes,
  fast = F
)
```

But getting below error:-

Error in sqlSave(channel = idisc_ODBC, dat = gaData, tablename = "GAData5",  : 
unable to append to table ‘GAData5’

Comment: why not use sqlupdate , it is faster than sqlsave. Syntax sqlUpdate(Connection details, data frame name ,tablename="", index= "primary key")

Comment: I don't have any primary key

Comment: than provide us some reproducible example using dput()